# Set up git to proxy server when proxy does not require username or password

Tags: git, http-proxy

I work behind a corporate firewall, but I have available to me a proxy server for when a tool or piece of software needs it. This proxy does not require a username or password and I have successfully used it in the past.

However, I am having trouble using it with git on windows. The command I use is this: "git config --global http.proxy http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx.x:8080"

I simply omit the username and password part of the command: "git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080"

But I get back an error when doing a git clone that says: "received http code 407 from proxy after CONNECT"

What am I doing wrong? is there no hope?

Comment: A 407 status code means, "proxy authentication required".  Maybe your proxy *does* require authentication?  You could try setting `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` (see  [git environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Networking)) to see if `git` is contacting the proxy you think it's contacting.

Comment: Error HTTP 407 Proxy authentication required

Comment: That is what I don't get. I have used this proxy for Eclipse and for RStudio without authentication. So I am asking if something else can possibly cause the 407 status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the proxy does need authentication. It uses my company windows credentials. The software I used the proxy on before was Windows software so it likely did that auth for me.